# Adding "OnClick" event to code behind button

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

So I've created a button, and I want to change its text by clicking on it.

This is my code behind  (this is from the Page_Load code) :

```
Button InviteToGameBTN = new Button();
InviteToGameBTN.Click += new EventHandler(InviteToGameBTN_OnClick);
```

.

```
protected void InviteToGameBTN_OnClick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
        Button b1 = (Button)sender;
        b1.Text = "Text changed";

}
```

What could be wrong ? 
Thanks to all.

Comment: What is the expected result and what is happening?

Comment: The expected results that the button's text change to "Text changed", but it's not heppening :\

Comment: Why don't you just add the button in the aspx page/file? Right now you are using a dynamic control, and correctly handling them in an Asp.Net Webforms application is a pain in the backside...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will 100% work but you may be able to use InviteToGameBTN.text to directly change it:

```
var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click += delegate
        {
            button.Text = "changed text";
        };
```

This was my little bit that I made in a new program, doesn't use an event handler but it uses the button.text to directly change its properties through the delegate { }